# SQL Query producing wrong count result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL query

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT
  count("SiteTree_Live"."ID") 
FROM  
  "SiteTree_Live"
  LEFT JOIN "Page_Live" ON "Page_Live"."ID" = "SiteTree_Live"."ID"
  LEFT JOIN "TourPage_Live" ON "TourPage_Live"."ID" = "SiteTree_Live"."ID"
  LEFT JOIN "DepartureDate" ON "DepartureDate"."TourID" = "SiteTree_Live"."ID"
WHERE 
  ("SiteTree_Live"."Locale" = 'en_AU')
  AND ("SiteTree_Live"."ClassName" IN ('TourPage'))
  AND ("DepartureDate"."DepartureDate" LIKE '2012-11%')
```

but it producing a wrong count as the query result. The total intented result this query is suppose to return should not be more than 245 but currently, its returning more than about "4569" results.

Thats is because of the JOIN on the "DepartureDate" table as the query returns the expected result when i remove the join from the "DepartureDate" table.

What modification do i need to make to my query to count the Macthes between "SiteTree_Live"."ID" and "DepartureDate"."TourID" whiles counting only the "SiteTree_Live"."ID" count excluding the Departure dates?

Any suggestions welcomed :)

THE ANSWER

```
SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT SiteTree_Live.ID) 
FROM 
"SiteTree_Live" LEFT JOIN "Page_Live" ON "Page_Live"."ID" = "SiteTree_Live"."ID" 
LEFT JOIN "TourPage_Live" ON "TourPage_Live"."ID" = "SiteTree_Live"."ID" 
LEFT JOIN "DepartureDate" ON "DepartureDate"."TourID" = "SiteTree_Live"."ID" 
WHERE 
("SiteTree_Live"."Locale" = 'en_AU') 
AND ("SiteTree_Live"."ClassName" IN ('TourPage'))
AND ("DepartureDate"."DepartureDate" LIKE '2013-03%')
```

Seems to give me the right result. Thanks for the tip @Michael Berkowski

Comment: Do you mean `COUNT(DISTINCT SiteTree_Live.ID)` instead of `DISTINCT COUNT()`?

Comment: Does this work at all? All your doublequotes should be backticks.

Comment: This `DepartureDate` is a character type ?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski  COUNT(DISTINCT SiteTree_Live.ID) seems to give me what i want. Cheers.. Thanks :)

Comment: @Barmar yes it does work

Comment: @wildplasser No the DepartureDate is a table name.

Comment: `AND ("DepartureDate"."DepartureDate" LIKE '2012-11%')` And also a column name.

Comment: @wildplasser Yes "DeparetureDate" is also a column name in table "DepartureDate"

Comment: But, what is its **type**? Date / datetime or char / varchar ?

Comment: @wildplasser its a date type. I have answered the question above already. and the query now works as intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor correction: if `DepartureDate` is a date-type, then the `LIKE '2013-03%` will force it to be coerced into a character type (this is a mysql *feature*) As a result, any indexes on `DepartureDate` will not be used, IIRC. Better use a plain range-query:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT stl.ID) 
FROM 
  SiteTree_Live stl
LEFT JOIN 
  DepartureDate dd ON dd.TourID = stl.ID 
WHERE 
  stl.Locale = 'en_AU'
  AND stl.ClassName = 'TourPage'
  AND dd.DepartureDate >= '2013-03-01'
  AND dd.DepartureDate < '2013-04-01'
   ;
```

Comment: Choosed this as the answer with a little edit. Thanks @wildplasser

Answer (score 1):

Do this (You have a bunch of unneeded joins)

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT SiteTree_Live.ID) 
FROM 
  `SiteTree_Live`
LEFT JOIN 
  `DepartureDate` ON `DepartureDate`.`TourID` = `SiteTree_Live`.`ID` 
WHERE 
  `SiteTree_Live`.`Locale` = 'en_AU'
  AND `SiteTree_Live`.`ClassName` = 'TourPage'
  AND `DepartureDate`.`DepartureDate` LIKE '2013-03%'
```

You could also do a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(SiteTree_Live.ID) 
FROM 
  `SiteTree_Live`
LEFT JOIN 
  `DepartureDate` ON `DepartureDate`.`TourID` = `SiteTree_Live`.`ID` 
WHERE 
  `SiteTree_Live`.`Locale` = 'en_AU'
  AND `SiteTree_Live`.`ClassName` = 'TourPage'
  AND `DepartureDate`.`DepartureDate` LIKE '2013-03%'
GROUP BY
  SiteTree_Live.ID
```